# SQL Inner Join giving wrong results

Tags: sql, ms-access

I know that the answer to this is going to be extremely simple and I've solved this problem before but for some reason I've been stuck on this for an hour.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT table1.FIELD1, table2.sum(FIELD2), table3.sum(FIELD3)
FROM (table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.JOBINSTID = table2.JOBINSTID)
     INNER JOIN table3 ON table1.JOBINSTID = table3.JOBINSTID
GROUP BY FIELD1;
```

The results that it returns are totally bonkers. Instead of giving me the actual sum of Field2 it gives me a number WAYYY higher. I know why this is happening and somewhat understand it but I don't know how to fix it. How do I change this query so that I get the correct sum?

**EDIT:** JOBINSTID is a unique ID in tables 1 and 2 but not in table 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's only a many-to-one problem involving table1, you might want this:

```
SELECT
  table2.FIELD1,
  SUM(table3.FIELD2)
FROM table2 JOIN table3
ON table3.JOBINST_ID = table2.JOBINSTID
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM table1
  WHERE table1.JOBINSTID = table2.JOBINSTID
  -- AND table1.JOBINSTID = table3.JOBINST_ID -- redundant, but might improve runtime
)
GROUP BY table2.FIELD1;
```

If the problem is (also) between table2 and table3, you may need to rethink how your database is normalized, but you could try this, which I think will work in any case:

```
SELECT -- DISTINCT -- add DISTINCT if FIELD1 values are not unique in table2
  table2.FIELD1,
  (
    SELECT SUM(FIELD2) FROM table3
    WHERE table3.JOBINST_ID = table2.JOBINSTID
  )
FROM table2
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM table1
  WHERE table1.JOBINSTID = table2.JOBINSTID
)
```

Given what you've said, it's hard to tell what you want, because you haven't described which relationships are 1-1 and which are many-1, or indicated which columns are unique in which tables.

Comment: Sorry, I was deliberately trying to keep it simple and left some details out. JOBINSTIDs are unique in tables 1 and 2 but not in table 3. I have edited the OP to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.It should work.

```
SELECT FIELD1, sum(FIELD2)
FROM table1 t1,table2 t2,table t3
WHERE.t1.JOBINSTID = t2.JOBINSTID
AND   t1.JOBINSTID = t3.JOBINST_ID
GROUP BY FIELD1;
```

PS: Give alias to the FIELD1,FIELD2 for which table you are using in SELECT CLAUSE.

Comment: Yeah, those parentheses worried me too. I don't *think* they have any effect, but then I never code that way, so who knows?

Comment: This query will work syntactically but Kittoes might be needing some other o/p i guess..

Comment: I believe the parentheses are an Access requirement as the code won't even run without them.

Comment: @Venk: That's what I'm saying. I'm using Access and therefore I have to use them.

Comment: You can try it other way... pls look at the modified one.

Comment: @Venk: Same result. Edited OP for clarity.

Comment: If you can post your input an desired output it would be much easier to help u...

Answer (score 0):

What table is `FIELD2` from? Guessing here: presumably, you want to sum each individual instance of `FIELD2`, but the query/data may be such that you are getting multiple instances of each `FIELD2`, due to a one-to-many relationship within your data. If so, the fix would be to revise your query so factor out duplicates of `FIELD2`.

Comment: You're right. The issue is that I'm getting multiple instances and I don't know how to revise the query to weed them out.